# Reading list of URLs from a file in R

Tags: r, file, url, screen-scraping

I have a file with a list of URLs

```
http://www.programmableweb.com/api-university
http://www.programmableweb.com/api-research
http://www.programmableweb.com/api/facebook
http://www.programmableweb.com/api/google-maps
```

I want to use R, in particular rvest for web scraping https://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/. I basically need to collect all the fields under SPECS like

```
    htmlpage <- read_html("http://www.programmableweb.com/api/swrve-events")
    text1 <- html_nodes(htmlpage, ".field")
```

Questions:

1. How do I read the file?
   When I do read.csv(filename) or read.table(filename) and then use read_html, it says

   ```
   no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
   ```
2. How do I iterate over the file?

Comment: You can lapply(readLines(filepath), function(eachlink) .......

Answer (score 0):

```
file_urls <- readLines ("path/to/file")
  node_data <- sapply(file_urls,function(i)read_html (i) %>% html_nodes (".field"))
```

Comment: @carl_boneri Thank you. What format is node_data? How do I save the output data to a file? I tried  datafile <- xmlToDataFrame(node_data) but it gave me the error:  Error in UseMethod("xmlSApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xmlSApply' applied to an object of class "xml_nodeset"

Comment: The format is an xml-nodeset. It's a list of each HTML element with the css class of ".field". As for saving...what have you done to the data/ what are you hoping to do to the data. Read the documentation on saveRDS. .. node_data is a data object in your workspace..so you can save however you would like

Comment: I'm assuming you just want the text...add "%>% html_text " to the chain and you should have a list of raw text instead of html objects

Comment: I want to analyze the output data. That is, I got all the fields for each API and now I need to aggregate over them to find the frequency of each field in all the APIs. I saved it as .rds and can read each entry with [n]. But, is there any other way that I can save the data so that it is easy to aggregate over? Maybe csv?

Comment: There is and are lots of ways. What have you tried to do?

Comment: I tried using aggregate() but it gives me the error Error in data.frame(`http://www.programmableweb.com/api/facebook` = c("",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 14, 6, 13, 15, 12, 11, 10, 7, 16, 8, 9, 5, 4, 3, 2, 17, 18, 0

Comment: Also lapply(node_data, FUN = length) gives me just the length of each node. I just need to know how to aggregate by specifying the string such as "API Provider" for example.

Comment: Right...because lapply (node_data,length) is asking "what is the length of each item in the data object 'node_data'" it isn't applying a function to each..but you are on the right track with your thinking on applying a function to each. Keep working on it.

Comment: I can access a particular element with lapply(node_data,"[", 2) but how do I specify the string? The elements are not the same for all nodes.

Comment: Try the help for grepl/grep. ?grepl . And then think in terms of lapply (node_data,function (i)ifelse (........

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message upon trying to read urls from a table imported from .csv file. I noticed that the table created by reading .csv file is of wrong type. Namely, the imported table "URLs" with 10 urls had the following properties:

```
> typeof(URLs)
[1] "list"
> length(URLs)
[1] 1
```

Meanwhile, I would like it to be:

```
> typeof(URLs)
[1] "character"
> length(URLs)
[1] 10
```

Thus I made the following workaround:

```
a<-character()
for (i in 1:10) {
  a[i]<-as.character(URLs[i,1])
}
```

Now I can see "a" as:

```
> typeof(a)
[1] "character"
> length(a)
[1] 10
```

And read_html command finally works:

```
> htmlpage <- read_html(a[i])
> show(htmlpage)
{xml_document}
<html lang="en">
[1] <head>\n<style>\r\n#headerlocal {\r\n    position: fixed;\r\n    z-index: 999;\r\n    top: 0;\r\n    height ...
[2] <body style="background-color:#eeeeee;"> \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\t\t<script type="text/javascript">\r\n\t\t\tcheck ...
```